# Can I trashcan blueprints?

Tags: raft

Early on I have very limited inventory / chest space, so I'd like it if [blueprints](https://raft.fandom.com/wiki/Blueprints) and recipes wouldn't take up slots. Is it safe to trashcan these items? The wiki suggests they are automatically researched, so do I even need them anymore?

Answer (score 3):

You can safely dispose of the blueprints as they are automatically learned as of Update 10. However, some players like to keep them as a collectible, so it would be down to your personal choice.